# Do I need a second (non-CPU) fan in my system?

Tags: cpu, fan, desktop-computer, temperature, speedfan

I have a mini-tower desktop PC containing (primarily) a MicroATX motherboard, 2 HDDs (2TB AND 3TB), one SSD, and one non-stock CPU fan (Arctic Cooler 11 LP). I've always felt this was sufficient, but we've recently had a very hot summer in the UK, reaching peaks of 28 degrees Celsius.

At 2AM yesterday, the temperature outside was 14 degrees Celsius, and these were the temperature readings I was getting from SpeedFan:

[image]

These temps are higher than I've ever noticed them, especially those of the HDDs, and my now-ancient Kingston SSD in particular is at 55 degrees - just high enough to trigger the red temperature warning in CrystalDiskInfo.

Is it necessary for me to take the sound (and financial) hit and find the space for a case fan in my system? In other words, is the rest of the summer at those temperatures likely to decrease the lifetime of my components significantly?

*Bonus question*: what is the difference between the CPU and the cores as measured by Speedfan? I'd always thought the cores made up the CPU - is this not the case?

Comment: More case fans are always better if you have a place to install them.

Comment: @Moab I'm aware they're better, just like any investment would be, but investments that aren't needed are a waste of money, especially on a low income. I'm asking whether it's needed for my system (i.e. whether the lifetime of the components will be significantly reduced by not having one).

Comment: your temps look fine for most standard hardware, but I would recommend a case fan (they are pretty cheap) just in case. the temperature of the air in the case limits the degree to which the CPU cooler can be effective during times of heavy use. you probably don't need it unless you start seeing higher temps, but it will make your system more robust.  also, you may want to double check your temp readings with a second utility, just to make sure speedfan is correctly calibrated for your hardware. only long term monitoring will tell if you need it; point in time measurements are unhelpful.

Comment: "whether the lifetime of the components will be significantly reduced by not having one" lower temps will always extend the life of electronics, only you can determine if it is worth the investment.

Comment: Is your case really that pressed for space? What kind of case do you have, and how many case fans do you currently have?

Comment: It's a mini-tower, here's the case and all the space left in it: https://imgur.com/a/sjsqkxO. If I did get a case fan it would probably have to be an exhaust.

Comment: Oh.....you don't even have an exhaust fan. In that case, I would definitely recommend getting one. The noise factor won't be too much if you get a good fan. I have two of these [Cougar fans](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835553001&cm_re=cougar_fan-_-35-553-001-_-Product). They are extremely quiet and move good air. If you have the ability to have an intake fan in the front, that could be a good addition along side the exhaust fan.

Comment: @DrZoo Absolutely no space in the front of the case at all, hence only the space for the exhaust fan. That fan you linked to is a lot cheaper than I expected it to be. Is it simple as mounting that to the open grill at the back of my case?

Comment: In order to avoid questions with multiple questions and multiple answers, please create a new question for you Speedfan "bonus question."

Comment: @Hashim - yes, it is as simple as screwing it in and plugging it into the motherboard or a spare power connector - plugging it into the motherboard is preferable - but they are different connectors, so make sure what you need before you buy it.

Comment: for your bonus question, its all about size and distance.  Cores generate a lot of heat in a very localized area, so a pair of cores may vary in temp up to 10-15C despite being only millimeters apart. There are several common measurements (where your sensors are installed) including TJunction (the individual core temp) and TCase (the temperature of the CPU exterior).  see more info here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005597/processors.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For peak performance and longevity, you should put in a fan, but there are compromises you can make.

First off, those temps are OK save for the SSD - so why not move the SSD position in the case?

With respect of other options - Intel (and probably AMD), CPUs all have thermal protection and downclock if they get too hot. This means you need not worry about the CPU overheating. I've used a converse of this - I deliberately limited the clock speed on my low-power 1st gen i5 CPU and ran the system WITHOUT ANY fans as a router for years. So you may want to limit your max speeds in hot temps.

Another consideration for fan noise - particularly a larger fan or multiple fans running at reduced speed. A large fan can move more air at a given speed, so you can reduce the speed of the fan to make it quieter.  Your system may also be able to adjust fan speed based on temp depending on the motherboard.  You can also mount a switch or - better, but more expensive - speed control knob on your case to allow you to control noise depending on task/temp.